# XSS - Anyway to bypass double quotes in href of anchor?

Tags: xss, javascript, html, reflected-xss

I have an anchor that has href attribute populated by my input. I am trying to input javascript, but it always renders it useless since it always appears between double quotes.

So far, I have tried many inputs including:

```
javascript:alert(1)
"javascript:alert(1)
"""javascript:alert(1)
" onclick=alert(1)
```

But, everytime the input comes inside double quotes and for `javascript:alert(1)` it is preceded by `unsafe:`. Is there anyway to bypass this?

Comment: This is a pure programming question. it is **off topic** on Security SE. I suggest to close it.

Answer (score -1):

make sure the `X-xss-protection` header is off and try your payload in another browser like Firefox

Comment: You forgot to specify that it's a header you need to disable (and how on earth would you do without access to the server!?) and what does the browser have to do anything here?